# Dependency Clash between Firestore and Support.Design

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-cloud-firestore

I am unable to install the following packages because their dependencies clash.

> Xamarin.Android.Support.Design v28.0.0.3
>
> Xamarin.Firebase.Firestore v71.1705.2

Has anybody managed to update their Firestore package after the new update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried to install Xamarin.Android.Support.Design `28.0.0.1` and Xamarin.Firebase.Firestore `71.1705.1`.

The steps is:

After I installed `Xamarin.Android.Support.Design v28.0.0.3`, I tried to install `Xamarin.Firebase.Firestore v71.1705.2`,it will throws such error:

> MyAndroidApp -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 28.0.0.3 ->
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 28.0.0.3)
>   MyAndroidApp ->Xamarin.Firebase.Firestore 71.1705.2 ->
>   Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement 71.1620.0 ->
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 28.0.0.1 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat
>   (= 28.0.0.1).

So ,I tried to install `Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 28.0.0.1`,after that, I tried to install `Xamarin.Firebase.Firestore v71.1705.2`,it will has this error:

> MyAndroidApp -> Xamarin.Firebase.Firestore 71.1705.2 ->
>   Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Runtime 1.1.1.3 ->
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations (= 28.0.0.3)
>    MyAndroidApp ->Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 28.0.0.1 ->
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations (= 28.0.0.1).

So, the version confict is `Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations (= 28.0.0.3)` and `Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations (= 28.0.0.1)`. then I tried to install a lower version of `Xamarin.Firebase.Firestore (71.1705.1)`, and then it works.

So, the problem is that the versions of some packages(e.g. `Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat`) in both nugets are not updated at the same time, which leads to conflicting versions

Comment: I am already using the package versions that you have mentioned. So there is no solution to have both package with the latest version together? Shouldn't this be reported as a bug?

Comment: Yes, you can report it as a bug here. https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues.